# Why can I not use math (subtraction) in a for-loop condition?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have two lists of strings, `listA` and `listB`. `listA` is longer, and I want to make `listB` the same size by adding empty strings to it.

This works:

```
int diff = listA.size() - listB.size()
for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    listB.add("");
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (listA.size() - listB.size()); i++) {
    listB.add("");
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because you are changing the size of listB

Comment: In the first case, `diff` is computed once before you enter the loop, and it's value stays the same. In the second case, `(listA.size() - listB.size())` is recomputed on every iteration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first example the variable `diff` is *constant* whereas the second example the condition is evaluated on each iteration of the loop and therefore since you're adding objects during iterations the size of the list will change hence why both code snippets don't do the same thing.

I'd recommend you proceed with the first approach i.e caching the limit for the loop condition beforehand and not re-evaluating it during each iteration.

Comment: Even better is to just have a `while (listA.size() > listB.size())` loop, since it's clearer what the intent is.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new value to `listB` the size will be incremented, so in each loop you the for loop re-evaluate  the size of  `listB` to find if the condition is `false` to stop the loop. in this case the condition will be `true` for ever because you add new element to the list

Answer (score 0):

The size of the List increments each time list.add ("") is called

All what ( listB.size () - listB.size ()) does each pass through the iteration  is compute new  size for the lists
i. e listB get a new size.

From your snippet diff == the size of the remaining you want to add items to listB

Option 1 will do.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already explained why your second loop didn't work.

I'd like to suggest an alternative approach that eliminates the loop by using `Collections.nCopies` and `List.addAll`:

```
if (listA.size() - listB.size() > 0) {
    listB.addAll(Collections.nCopies(listA.size() - listB.size(), ""));
}
```

or

```
int diff = listA.size() - listB.size();
if (diff > 0) {
    listB.addAll(Collections.nCopies(diff, ""));
}
```